# Java convert Html to Image

Tags: java, html

I generated a Html with information of my client, so that he can attach them to your website or email.
But some clients asked me to generate an image and not the html. I used the code below to generate the image, and it went well, but the image contained in the html is not being generated. When I open the HTML code in browser it works correctly, but when I generated the image from html, it generates only text and breaks the image.

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
String html = "<body lang=PT-BR style='tab-interval:35.4pt'><img src='http://nxcache.nexon.net/all/v1.5.2/img/gnt/games-dropdown/maplestory.jpg'></body>";

int width = 600, height = 200;

BufferedImage image = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
    .getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration()
    .createCompatibleImage(width, height);

Graphics graphics = image.createGraphics();

JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane("text/html", html);
jep.setSize(width, height);
jep.print(graphics);

ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("C:\\Users\\MYUSER\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\HtmlToImage\\Image.png"));
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be happening?

This is my problem in picture. --> [Erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZSHA.png)

project on git: [github](http://github.com/dragoso/HtmlToImage)

Comment: I can't find any source for what I am about to say. But as far as I remember, swing does not support images that are loaded from the web. There is definitely a way to show images that are stored on the classpath- and I believe that it is also possible to show images that are stored in a file. 

Maybe, downloading that image and storing it in a temp directory might be the solution (you'll then need to pass the path to that file into your image). 

Alternatively, check out openhtmltopdf - it's a more sophisticated tool to convert html to pdfs and images.

Comment: Already stored the image in a local repository to try, and also did not work. But I will check the tool you talked about. Thank you.

Comment: It would be probably helpful if you added a minimal example of the generated html. Also, you could explain better, maybe with an image, what do you mean with "the image contained in the html is not being generated".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of this library https://code.google.com/archive/p/java-html2image/ which provides options to convert html to image.

Code will look something like this.

```
String html = "<body lang=PT-BR style='tab-interval:35.4pt'><img src='http://nxcache.nexon.net/all/v1.5.2/img/gnt/games-dropdown/maplestory.jpg'></body>";

            HtmlImageGenerator hig = new HtmlImageGenerator();
            hig.loadHtml(html);
            hig.saveAsImage(new File("test.png"));
```

Comment: The same problem occurred as well. The image generates but the images contained in the HTML are broken.

Comment: For me it worked with the html code you provided. Can you provide complete HTML code

Comment: This is project on git https://github.com/dragoso/HtmlToImage

Comment: its working fine with the code you shared in my local. Image is same as showing in HTML, Are you using any proxy server while executing this ?

Comment: The problem persist in another computer, In html is this---> https://ibb.co/8z7g4Km

Comment: ibb.co/8z7g4Km  is the image generated in my local

Comment: which JDK u r using

Comment: java jdk 8- 111

Comment: the project link is broken. it isnt working for me

Answer (score 4):

Using `java-html2image` (https://github.com/hkirk/java-html2image):

```xml
// pom.xml
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>jitpack.io</id>
    <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
...
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.hkirk</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-html2image</artifactId>
    <version>0.9</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

```java
public void testing() {
    HtmlImageGenerator imageGenerator = new HtmlImageGenerator();
    imageGenerator.loadHtml("<body><span>Hello World!</span></body>");
    imageGenerator.saveAsImage("testing.png");
}
```

The bad part of using `java-html2image` is: the output image always has white borders (so having black background is impossible).

---

**Updates:**

I found the solution for the white border issue:

```java
HtmlImageGenerator imageGenerator = new HtmlImageGenerator() {
    protected JEditorPane createJEditorPane() {
        JEditorPane editor = super.createJEditorPane();
        editor.setOpaque(false); // The solution
        return editor;
    }
};
```

Now the output image is clear!